# Convolution of $\int f(x,y,z) dy$ and $\int g(z,y,z) dy$

Tags: integration, convolution

Edit: I denote ***, **, * for 3D, 2D, 1D convolution, respectively.

Let's denote an operator $R$ as

$$R[f](x,z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y,z) dy \tag{1}$$

where $f$ has compact support. Then, I want to evaluate

$$R[f \ast\ast\ast g](x,z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  (f \ast\ast\ast g) (x,y,z) \,dy$$

1. I wonder if $R[f \ast\ast\ast g] = R[f] \ast\ast R[g]$ holds. $R[f]$ becomes 2-dimensional function. I feel that it doesn't hold in general, but I'm not sure.
2. Or wonder if it can be simplified if $g$ is a well-known function like Gaussian.

---

Context: In 2D, $R$ is similar to 2D Radon transform for a fixed angle and it is known that $\text{Radon}[f*\ast g]=\text{Radon}[f]*\text{Radon}[g]$. But I'm not sure about the case in (1) where $R$ is not Radon transform, but involved with a line integral.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are three variable functions and $*$ is the two variable convolution, which variables are convoluted?

Comment: $f*g$ is involved with 3d convolution but $R[f]$ and $R[g]$ are 2 dimensional variables of $x$ and $z$. So $R[f] \ast R[g]$ has two dimensional convolution. Sorry for the confusion.